# Can I search YouTube by reverse date, to find the oldest videos matching my criteria?

Tags: youtube

I want to find the oldest videos matching a certain search string - can this be done in any way?

Unfortunately the suggested method of sorting by date and viewing the last page limits me to 1000 results back, which in the case of most searches is a only few months. I want to find the oldest results.

Answer (score 18):

I couldn't find any option that works from within Youtube and as OP mentions there is an annoying 1000 video limit preventing going back further with popular searches.

<s>The best alternative I found is to use Google with `site:youtube.com` and `Sorted by date` with the additional option of using `Custom date range` to narrow the search further.</s>

Since 2019 [Google dropped](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-drops-sort-by-date-before-and-after-commands-27393.html) `Sorted by Date` option but added a `before:` option which also works in YouTube. Therefore in combination with sorting by Upload date you can limit the results and easily scroll down to the first video.

Here is an example of finding the first upload referencing the WRC Rally as `wrc` and narrowed with `before:2005-11-01`:

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wrc+before%3A2005-11-01&sp=CAI%253D
```

Comment: Recently, I just typed in the search bar, Dragon Ball Z before:2009 and did it work!

Comment: This dosen't seem to work on people.

Answer (score -1):

Sort video on 'upload date' and go to the last page.

1. Insert your search keywords
2. Then select: Search Option-> Sort by: upload date
3. Go to last page

Answer (score -1):

I found that going to "Upload date" and adding `_reverse` at the end of the URL usually works.